# Why is process.nextTick wrapped in a Promise in this statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please help me understand the "mechanics" of this line of code:

```js
await new Promise(process.nextTick)
```

My educated guess, based on this [description of the Promise() constructor from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) and these [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processnexttickcallback-args):

1. We call `new Promise` to create a new Promise object.
2. `process.nextTick` (aka the `executor`) is passed to the Promise constructor.
3. The Promise constructor automatically generates two functions: `resolve` and `reject`.
4. `process.nextTick` is called with `resolve` and `reject` as arguments.
5. `resolve` becomes the `process.nextTick`'s callback.
6. Because `process.nextTick` only accepts one callback, `reject` becomes an additional argument that will be passed to the `process.nextTick`'s callback (`resolve`) when `resolve` is called.

For illustrative purposes:

```js
// This is "pseudocode"
process.nextTick(resolve) // <-- `resolve` becomes the callback
resolve(reject)           // <-- `reject` becomes an argument to `resolve`
```

7. `process.nextTick` pushes `resolve` to the next tick queue.
8. When it's time to execute the next tick queue, `resolve` is called with `reject` passed to it as an argument.
9. `reject` is a function so it will probably resolve to `undefined`.
10. `resolve` will fulfill the promise with the value of `undefined`.
11. The promise is now resolved and `await` unwraps it to deliver `undefined`.
12. The execution of the statement is completed and the control is passed to the next thing in the event loop. We are now one tick ahead.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Do you know what the Promise constructor takes? Read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise. The executor is a function that's called with two callbacks. Then look at https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processnexttickcallback-args - nextTick is a function that takes a callback. The return value of nextTick/the executor is irrelevant, and it _is_ called with a function.

Comment: Ugh! I just wrote a really complete answer  and then the question got closed. @trincot

Comment: It's just a misunderstanding that the function isn't *called* (immediately), but *passed*. Duplicate, no? The promise API will do the calling and will pass the argument.

Comment: @Barmar reopened, but also edited heavily

Comment: @303 Steps 10/11 are incorrect. A function is not ignored, it's a value like any other object. The promise is actually fulfilled with the function. You can check with `console.log(await new Promise(process.nextTick))`. Everything else in your description is fine.

Comment: "reject is a function so it will probably resolve to undefined." `reject` is never called, so the argument to `resolve()` will just be the function object itself.

Comment: Since you never assign the result of `await` to anything, it doesn't matter what the promise resolves to. The only point of this is to delay the following code until the next tick.

Comment: Before promises, the way you would do this is with `setTimeout(function..., 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is process.nextTick wrapped in a Promise in this statement?

The core reason for doing this in a piece of code is to use promises to wait for any other code after this function call to execute and to not proceed until that code finishes whatever it meant to do and returns control back to the event system.

The particular reason for desiring that behavior depends entirely upon what the code is doing, but often its a way of forcing something to always behave asynchronously, even if sometimes the result is known synchronously as this presents a consistent asynchronous behavior to the caller and results in fewer bugs in cases where a function may sometimes have an asynchronous result and sometimes a synchronous result.  For example, any normally asynchronous operation with a local cache may actually know the result synchronously if it's found in the local cache, but for consistency of behavior for the caller, it wants to always deliver the result asynchronously.

Wrapping `process.nextTick()` in a promise is likely done just to allow the local use of promises for flow control rather than the plain callbacks of `process.nextTick()`, essentially the same reason as anything else is "promisified".

Your understanding in your question is mostly correct. I'll explain the big picture first and then address a few minor tweaks in your points.

This code structure:

```
await new Promise(process.nextTick)
```

is essentially a shortcut way of expressing things that is easier to understand in a non-shortcut version like this:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.nextTick(resolve, reject);
});
```

Or, even further unwrapped:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.nextTick((rej) => {
        resolve(rej);
    }, reject);
});
```

So, you can see that it creates a promise that gets resolves when `process.nextTick()` calls its callback.

The key to understanding it is this series of steps:

1. `new Promise(process.nextTick)` is creating a new promise and passing as the executor function to the new Promise the function reference `process.nextTick`.
2. That Promise constructor will call `process.nextTick(resolve, reject)` as its executor function - e.g. the callback you pass to `new Promise()`.
3. When the new Promise calls its executor function, it passes two arguments to that executor function the `resolve` and `reject` functions which will end up being `process.nextTick(resolve, reject)`.
4. When `process.nextTick()` gets to the next tick, it will call its callback function (the first argument passed to it and will pass any arguments that it received beyond the first callback argument).  The second argument passed to `process.nextTick()` which is the `reject` function reference is actually passed as an argument to the first argument callback since any argument beyond the first one is passed as an argument to the callback.

---

Some small corrections to your points:

**9. reject is a function so it will probably resolve to undefined.**

You are correct that it is called as `resolve(reject)`, but a function is just fine as a resolved value so it doesn't resolve to `undefined`.  It resolves to the reject handler from the executor.  That's largely immaterial to your code since you don't do anything with the resolved value, but your point 9 wasn't quite correct in this regard.

**10. resolve will fulfill the promise with the value of undefined.**

See description above for point 9.  The resolved value will be the reject function.

**11. The promise is now resolved and await unwraps it to deliver undefined.**

`await` is delivered the `reject` function as the resolved value.

Comment: "to wait for any other code after this function call to execute". This is very vague. Which function is being referred to? It's also easy to misinterpret as meaning code that literally occurs after (i.e. below) this statement, which is not the case. This statement yields execution back to the event loop, so the statement can be used to defer to any other microtasks scheduled to run in the current tick before continuing.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 - `await` does NOT yield execution back to the event loop.  Instead, it causes the containing `async` function to immediately return a promise and the code in the calling function right after where is called this function can then execute. So, `await new Promise(process.nextTick)` lets the rest of the current thread of execution unwind and eventually return back to the event loop before executing the next statement in the original function that's right after `await new Promise(process.nextTick)`.